# Returning an Action route another MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm currently creating an admin tool for a new project which I would like to use to retrieve a url from a different project in my solution.

Although the product controller doesn't exist in the project I am calling it from, I would like to retrieve it from the first project.

Is this at all possible, or would I need to create some sort of helper method in the first project?!

Many thanks in advance.

**Update for clarity**

For example, let's say that I am building a sitemap generator. Let's say I have a route in my first project:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Product",
  "products/{Title}-{Id}",
  new { controller = "Product", action = "Details" }
);
```

And let's say that I have product with the title 'Buzz Cola' with an id of 8. This would generate the url:

```
products/buzz_cola-8  (title has been cleaned, but constraints are not shown here)
```

So, in my second project, there is no "Product" route, and there is no Product controller, but I'd like to create one in a function that would do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ProductInfo> products = MyServiceLayer.GetAllProducts();
List<string> productUrls
foreach(ProductInfo productInfo in products)
{
  productUrls.Add(
    FirstProject.Action("Details", "Product", new { Title = CleanTitle(productInfo.Title), Id = ProductInfo.Id });
  );
}
```

At the end of this, productUrls would contain something like:

```
products/slurm_cola-1
products/hotdogs-2
products/squishy-3
products/buzz_cola-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a controller that inherits from the controller in the second project

Comment: I'm lost. How would that help me generate the url from the first project?

Comment: what do you mean by 'retrieve url'?

Comment: Aouida, I have clarified the question a bit better.

Thanks.